# Cordova windows 10 add confirm message on software close button / alt+F4

Tags: cordova, uwp, winjs, cordova-win10

How can I display a confirm message when user click on the software close button (X / Alt+F4) of a Cordova application running on windows 10 (desktop). I have tryed few things but nothing work:

```
//This only fire when clicking on the back arrow.
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown.bind(this), false); 
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    navigator.notification.alert('onBackKeyDown');
}

//This fire but to late and cannot cancel or display message
document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
function onPause() {
    debugger;
    navigator.notification.alert('onPause');
};

//This is never fired
WinJS.Application.addEventListener("unload", unloadEv);
function unloadEv(ev) {
    navigator.notification.alert('unloadEv');
}

//This is never fired
window.onbeforeunload = onbeforeunload;
function onbeforeunload(evt) {
    navigator.notification.alert('onbeforeunload');
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685285/override-close-box-on-window-10-universal-apps-uwp . This isn't wrapped by Cordova but you can register for the CloseRequested event in platform specific JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step : 1**

Close button is restricted Capabilities function to enable this

Open `package.windows10.appxmanifest` on `platform -> windows` Folder.

**Step : 2**

In that xml package tag should like this

`<Package IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10">`

In Capabilities tag add `<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />`

`<Capabilities>
     <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
 </Capabilities>`

Here `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapa` and `IgnorableNamespaces="rescap"` is Enabling restricted Capabilities.

**Step : 3**

And add below javascript code on your js file and build

```
 Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview.getForCurrentView().oncloserequested = function (args) {
            args.detail[0].handled = true;
            var message = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Details is not Saved Do you want save or exit the application..?");
            message.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Save", SaveHandler));
            message.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Exit", UnsaveHandler));
            message.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Cancel", CancelHandler));
            message.showAsync();
        }
        function SaveHandler(command) {
                //save button
        }
        function CancelHandler(command){
            return false;
        }
        function UnsaveHandler(command) {
            window.close();
        }
```