# How to know UWP OnClosing event?

Tags: uwp

How to catch the OnClosing event like WinForm on uwp?

On desktop, we always close the app by clicking the "Close" button on the top-right corner.

I want to do something before closing.

Comment: This is not an easy question to answer... depends a bit on what you want to do, because the lifecycle of an UWP app is different than traditional apps. So take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle that should help you decide.

Comment: Paint 3D can do it before you closing it. It will ask you to save the work. I want this.

Comment: Readup on this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-close

Comment: I'm still confused, they don't give samples, just a few words.

Comment: Maybe this example can help you more https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicSuspension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you can't. But you can use the confirmAppClose capability to override the close button. To use this capability, you need to add it on your appxmanifest, AND, ask Microsoft to get the certification.

[Override Close Box on Window 10 Universal Apps UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685285/override-close-box-on-window-10-universal-apps-uwp)